# WSL Ubuntu ~/ssh/config symlinked to c:\users\USER\.ssh\config permissions error

Tags: ssh, permissions, openssh, symbolic-link, wsl2

*Reposting from StackOverflow on another users request*

I'm trying to use a symlink to simplify my SSH config management. My reasoning is that I use CMD for SSH when at home and WSL Ubuntu when in the office. I prefer to use WSL but due to using a Cisco VPN client, it's a pain to get WSL Ubuntu to work. Plus, VS Code works off of the file located in my windows home directory anyway.

How can I work around the permissions error I get when doing the titled symbolic link?

```
hardya@MYLAPTOP:~/.ssh$ ssh someServer 
Bad owner or permissions on /home/hardya/.ssh/config

hardya@MYLAPTOP:~/.ssh$ ll
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  2 hardya hardya  4096 Jul 20 16:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 hardya hardya  4096 Jul 20 15:37 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 hardya hardya    31 Jul 20 16:06 config -> /mnt/c/Users/hardya/.ssh/config*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 hardya hardya  1941 May 19 11:25 config.old*
-rw-------  1 hardya hardya  1823 Oct 27  2020 id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x  1 hardya hardya   401 Oct 27  2020 id_rsa.pub*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 hardya hardya 41772 May 19 11:25 known_hosts*

hardya@MYLAPTOP:~/.ssh$ ll /mnt/c/Users/hardya/.ssh/
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 1 hardya hardya   512 Jul 20 15:36 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 hardya hardya   512 Jul 13 13:56 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hardya hardya  3045 Jul 20 16:05 config*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hardya hardya  1823 Jun  7  2019 id_rsa*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hardya hardya   401 Jun  7  2019 id_rsa.pub*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hardya hardya 15815 Jul 12 16:25 known_hosts*
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Have you tried to simply delete the configuration file, specifically rename it to something else, and/or uninstall and reinstall OpenSSH Server windows feature to recreate the configuration file?  Your keys are also the incorrect permission by the way.  Honestly, the failure more than likely, is due to the symlinked status of the file.

Comment: Thanks for moving it over here.  Don't forget to delete the question on Stack Overflow, since (a) it's off-topic there and (b) cross-posting is frowned upon.  Thanks!  I'll try to find some time to test this out myself, since I'm setup with both Windows SSH and WSL as well.  I'm thinking it may be due to the way that WSL maps Windows permissions -- There's a solution if that's the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Short Answer:*

Create a `/etc/wsl.conf` in your WSL instance (you'll need to use `sudo`) with the following contents:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
```

Then exit and restart the distribution with either `wsl --terminate <distroname>` or `wsl --shutdown` (from PowerShell or CMD).<sup>**1**</sup>

The `fmask` should give the `config` the permissions it needs, at least.  But you'll still run into problems when you try to use your private key, since it can't be world-readable.

You can either set your `fmask` to be more restrictive or (since we've enabled metadata) you can `chmod 400 id_rsa`.

*Explanation:*

I can reproduce your issue *if* I comment-out my `/etc/wsl.conf`.  I'm assuming you've never set one up, which is likely the real problem.  The fact that all of the files in your `/mnt/c/Users/hardya/.ssh/` showed with permissions 777 is the hint here.  And, of course, the problem, since '~/.ssh/config` can't be world-writable.  The fact that it's symlinked is mostly a red-herring.

By default in WSL, DrvFS/9P mounts [do not have metadata support enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions#drvfs-file-does-not-have-metadata-default).  Without this extra metadata, WSL can't "pretend" to set permissions on those files.  So it just does a mapping as specified in that doc.  Basically, if your user has read-write-execute permissions in Windows, then the file will be set with user, group, and other of read-write-execute (i.e. `rwxrwxrwx` or `777`).

That's because everything in WSL is effectively running as your Windows user anyway.  So it's not *wrong* that those are the permissions.  But it can get in the way of Linux apps/services that assume Linux-like permissions.  So Linux's `ssh` sees `777` on the `config` and rightly refuses to run.  It doesn't know that the Windows permissions are restrictive enough - It just knows what the Linux `stat` tells it.

That's where the metadata comes in.  With the `metadata` option turned on, you can `chmod` files on the Windows drive and WSL will store the new permissions in metadata.  I.e. if you `chmod 400` a file, your user in WSL won't be able to change it even though the Windows user really has permission to anyway.  The WSL root user, of course, could still make a change.

Without `metadata`, a `chmod` on a Windows file simply has no effect.

The `umask`/`fmask`, on the other hand, specify the *default* permissions that Windows files should appear with to WSL in absence of any metadata.  So by giving files a default of 744, you at least placate `ssh` by making `config` no longer world-writable.

<sub><sup>**1**</sup>Thanks to [@Ino](https://superuser.com/users/857347/ino) in the comments for reminding me that I missed this step in my original write-up!</sub>

Comment: Just adding link to Microsoft documentation about `wsl.conf` and `.wslconf` configuration files [Advanced settings configuration in WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config)

Comment: Do not forget to restart the WSL service `LxssManager`  to remount the C: drive. Do it from PowerShell using `Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service;Get-Service -name lxssmanager` or using net command `net.exe stop LxssManager ;  net.exe start LxssManager`

Comment: @ino Good point that a restart is always needed when changing the `/etc/wsl.conf`, but a simple `wsl --terminate <distro>` should suffice in this case.  At worst, a `wsl --shutdown` is needed, but that generally impacts the root namespace for *all* distributions, so it shouldn't be necessary in this case.  Honestly, in the last 2 years or so, I've only had to actually restart the LxxManager service maybe 3 times -- Only when there's been a hard lockup of WSL.