# Connect VSCode editor to remote with WSL SSH key

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with WSL on Windows 10.  I set up SSH keys with my remote server and they are stored for that WSL user `~/.ssh/` full path from windows would look like `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\zac\.ssh`

This connection works great for connecting via the WSL terminal `ssh root@82.1xx.xxx.xx`

I am hoping to also be able connect the editor portion of VSCode to this remote server.  I installed the Remote - SSH extension and all the other related Remote Development tools.   After Googling around I have tried [this solution](https://zitseng.com/archives/20325), for my windows user I have created a file called `ssh.bat` that contains the following:

`C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe ssh %*`

Then from the Remote SSH:Config file I added my path to that file

`C:\Users\Zac\bin\ssh.bat`

When I try connect to host this is written to that .bat file

```
Host 82.1xx.xxx.xx
  HostName 82.1xx.xxx.xx
  User root
```

And there is a lengthy error output, here is some of the output:

```
[13:30:34.121] The specified path C:\Users\zac\bin\ssh.bat is not a valid SSH binary
[13:30:34.121] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[13:30:34.157] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[13:30:34.162] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\Zac\bin\ssh.bat"
[13:30:34.162] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 60600 -F "C:\Users\Zac\bin\ssh.bat" "82.1xx.xxx.xx" bash
[13:30:34.165] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:30:34.421] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:30:34.421] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[13:30:34.439] > C:\\Users\\Zac\\bin\\ssh.bat: line 1: Bad configuration option: c:\\windows\\sys
> tem32\\wsl.exe
> C:\\Users\\Zac\\bin\\ssh.bat: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> 
[13:30:35.710] "install" terminal command done
[13:30:35.711] Install terminal quit with output: C:\\Users\\Zac\\bin\\ssh.bat: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
[13:30:35.711] Received install output: C:\\Users\\Zac\\bin\\ssh.bat: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
[13:30:35.712] Failed to parse remote port from server output
```

Hoping to make this solution work or I am fine if there is a way to synch the environments or even just a copy of the key for both?  I am not sure how that would work and imagine there would be a lot of permission issues.

Comment: It might simplify things if you just used the built-in OpenSSH capability within Windows instead of using OpenSSH within WSL.

Comment: Not quite sure why it's failing yet - Still noodling through that part.  But if you want to try the "keep one copy of the key", see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1663858/1210833) (although I have a feeling you have already seen it, since it just got an upvote).  Let me know if you have any trouble with that part, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have SSH in windows as well but it is more important to me to connect from WSL, I just would like to be able to run the editor too with that connection.  Maybe I can just have two different keys going now that I am typing this out..    I will check out that other question thanks!